# incrementally reveal columns of a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles

I would like to incrementally or animatedly reveal the elements of a matrix.  Ideally I would like to just fade in the elements (à la beamer's overlay) from gray to black on each advance but I woul dsettle for a change of background to the cell (from a light gray to white).  What I have is unsatisfactory:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % \tikzstyle{unseen} = [color=blue!70]
      \tikzstyle{seen} = []
      \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
      nodes in empty cells,
      minimum size=7mm, ampersand replacement=\&, every
      node/.style={font={\large\ttfamily\bfseries},fill=gray!10}] {
        1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \\
        0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \\
        0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \\
        0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \\
        0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \\
       };
       \foreach \f/\r/\c in {1/2/1,2/3/1} {
         \draw<\f->[seen] (m-\r-\c.north west) rectangle (m-\r-\c.south east);
       }
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Since these are (for now) sparse binary matrices could I make the `foreach` list insert the `1` entries?

All help or suggestions gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax could be hidden a bit and I'm not quite sure about the first column squares but something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{}

\newcommand\showmatrix{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}
      % \tikzstyle{unseen} = [color=blue!70]
      \tikzstyle{seen} = []
      \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
      nodes in empty cells,
      minimum size=7mm, ampersand replacement=\&, every
      node/.style={font={\large\ttfamily\bfseries},fill=gray!10}] {
      \zz  1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \\
      \zz  0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \\
      \zz  0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \\
      \zz  0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \\
      \zz  0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \\
       };
       \foreach \f/\r/\c in {1/2/1,2/3/1} {
         \draw<\f->[seen] (m-\r-\c.north west) rectangle (m-\r-\c.south east);
       }
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\def\zz#1\&#2\\{#1\\}%
\only<1>{\showmatrix}%
\def\zz#1\&#2\&#3\\{#1\&#2\\}%
\only<2>{\showmatrix}%
\def\zz#1\&#2\&#3\&#4\\{#1\&#2\&#3\\}%
\only<3>{\showmatrix}%
\def\zz#1\&#2\&#3\&#4\&#5\\{#1\&#2\&#3\&#4\\}%
\only<4>{\showmatrix}%
\def\zz#1\&#2\&#3\&#4\&#5\&#6\\{#1\&#2\&#3\&#4\&#5\\}%
\only<5>{\showmatrix}%
\def\zz#1\&#2\&#3\&#4\&#5\&#6\&#7\\{#1\&#2\&#3\&#4\&#5\&#6\\}%
\only<6>{\showmatrix}%
\def\zz#1\&#2\&#3\&#4\&#5\&#6\&#7\\{#1\&#2\&#3\&#4\&#5\&#6\&#7\\}%
\only<7>{\showmatrix}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, the squares may have caused confusion but what I was attempting to capture was that on each successive overlay the next entry of the matrix would be revealed or emphasised.  Since not many of the entries would be '1' I had been toying with framing these interesting ones in a foreach loop.  Changing the typeface to bold would have been my preference.  Thanks for the fast response, though.

Comment: @healyp I revealed column by column as that is what the question in the title asks for, your wording in t comment though suggests you actually want to reveal the non zero elements element by element which is a rather different question?

Comment: Agreed.  Poorly worded question title.  I will reformulate more precisely as a new question.  Thanks for the assistance.